# Convert Date from 6/05/2020 format to dd/MM/YYYY format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetime-format

I am facing a small issue which i am not able after trying so many things so here it goes ..... There is a text box in my page in which i am entering date and i want that date in a datetime object.

for ex :
date entd : 6 05 2020(dd/MM/yyyy) should be in same format when i am accessing it in date time object but it is getting changed to (6.05.2020ie: MM/dd/yyyy format).

i hope i am making sense here all i want is some thing like this.....

```
DateTime dt = convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
```

dt should be (11/2/2010  rather then 2/11/2010)

@oded after using the following code

```
DateTime sDate, eDate = new DateTime();
```

//To modify dates for our use. 
    DateTime.TryParseExact(txtFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out sDate);

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(txtFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out eDate);
```

What i am getting in edate and sdate is 6 05 2020 12:00:00 AM where it should be 6/05/2020

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  A DateTime object should not have a "format" except in that it has an implementation of ToString().  You should be able to display it in any way you like.

Comment: Why not use a CalenderExtender with it's format like this `CalenderExtender1.Format = "dd.MM.yyy";` from AjaxControlToolkit?I do not think it is safe to type the date users may enter anything who do not know how your date textbox works.

Comment: If you are getting 1/1/0001/ that means the text being parsed is invalid.  I would simply use a CalenderExtender, because what you want to do, would require to much work to make it worth while.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: This value: "11/2/2010" doesn't match the format "dd/MM/yyyy". It matches the format "d/M/yyyy" - for "dd/MM/yyyy" it should be "11/02/2010".

That's why `TryParseExact` is failing for you. You need to pick the right format pattern.

---

A `DateTime` value *doesn't have a format*. It just represents date and time (in the ISO calendar, and possibly in different time zones, but that's a different matter). It's like an `int` - it doesn't represent "a decimal integer" or "a hex integer" - it's just an integer within a particular range. You can *format* a number as decimal or hex, but it doesn't inherently have a format.

It sounds like you should parse it with `ParseExact` to specify the format when converting *from* the textbox, or probably [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx):

```
// This is assuming you're absolutely sure of the format used. This is *not*
// necessarily the user's preferred format. You should think about where your
// data is coming from.
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // Okay, successful parse. We now have the date. Use it, avoiding formatting
    // it back to a string for as long as possible.
}
```

You should keep that value as `DateTime` for all purposes *except* giving it back to a user - at which point you may well want to use their cultural settings.

In particular, if you're storing the value in a database you *should not* convert it to text and include it in a SQL statement - that's asking for trouble. Instead, use a parameterized SQL statement and set it as the parameter value, still as a `DateTime`.

Comment: DateTime sDate, eDate = new DateTime(); //To modify dates for our use. DateTime.TryParseExact(txtFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out sDate); DateTime.TryParseExact(txtFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out eDate); What i am getting in edate and sdate is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM where it should be 3/11/2011 i think you got my point the out put is not correct thats my concern only.

Comment: @ankur: You're ignoring the return value of `TryParseExact`, which is almost certainly false. What's the value of `txtFrom.Text` here? You talk about "that's my concern only" - but it strikes me that you're still fundamentally missing the point that a DateTime doesn't have a format. What you might happen to see in a debugger will be *a formatted representation* but that's not the same as the value inside the DateTime itself.

Comment: @ankur: See the update to my answer, at the top - if you're trying to parse "11/2/2010" as if the month is specified in "MM" format (i.e. *exactly two digits*) then that parse will indeed fail.

Comment: thank you for pointing but the problem is still there i will explain and also paste the code sample . what i entered in sDate = 3/11/2011 and in eDate = 25/6/2002 so the values i got is eDate = 6/25/2002 (wrong) and sDate = 1/1/0001 (wrong). my code         DateTime.TryParseExact(txtFrom.Text, "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out sDate);

        DateTime.TryParseExact(txtTo.Text, "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out eDate);

Comment: @ankur: No, `eDate` is a DateTime. It isn't 6/25/2002, it's a value representing the 25th of June 2002. *Don't look at the debugger representation of the whole `DateTime` value to try to determine a string format*. That's confusing you. Use `dt.Month` etc to work out what the value is. And `3/11/2011` doesn't fit "dd/M/yyyy" because you've only given a single *day* value. It sounds like you might want "d/M/yyyy" as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 11):

`DateTime` doesn't store dates in any specific format - it uses an internal representation (what exactly shouldn't matter).

After parsing the string to a `DateTime`, there is no inherent format there. There is only a format when you *output* the value. What you see in the debugger is simply a conversion to a string using your system settings.

If you want to format the `DateTime`, use `ToString` with a format string:

```
dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

The converse also applies - if you need to parse the string unambiguously, use `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` (both static members of of `DateTime`):

```
DateTime dt;

if(DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out td))
{
  // Valid date used in `txtDate.Text`, use dt now.
}
```

Read about [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) Date and Time format strings.

Comment: it is again in string since you have used ToString i dont need that i need the thing in dattime object. can you provide some code snippet for same by picking value from text box and then modifying its format to dd/MM/yyyy in a date time object again.

Comment: @ankur - A `DateTime` doesn't have a format. You only format it out to a string.

Comment: @Oded: It sounds like the more important part here is *parsing*, not formatting. "There is a text box in my page in which i am entering date and i want that date in a datetime object." - that's a parsing task.

Comment: Why not use a CalenderExtender with it's format like this `CalenderExtender1.Format = "dd.MM.yyy";`?

Comment: @ankur - Oded is correct- keep the value internally DateTime wherever possible (never pass it round as a String internally) - this saves you much frustration with TimeZones, formats etc. You only need to worry about formatting when showing the datetime to humans - on screens, reports etc.

Comment: @Jon - After reading your answer, I revised mine, though the OP has an inherent misunderstanding about the relationship between `DateTime` and formatting.

Comment: @Oded: Agreed, and hopefully we'll get there... I'll keep my similar answer for the moment, as we can each edit ours independently until one "clicks" for the OP.

Comment: @JonSkeet nice catch.. about parsing. many times it saves my time :) +1 for parsing

Comment: @oded what i got after using your code is not what i was looking for. so here is my code DateTime sDate, eDate = new DateTime();
        
        //To modify dates for our use.
        DateTime.TryParseExact(txtFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out sDate);

        DateTime.TryParseExact(txtFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out eDate);
What i am getting in edate and sdate is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM where it should be 3/11/2011 that i  entered

Comment: @ankur - Please add details by _editing_ the question and posting there there. Comments are a poor place for code examples.

Comment: @ankur - The reason `TryParseExact` is in an `if` is that it returns `false` if the parse failed, which it seems to have. Check that the string you pass in matches the format you use - it must be _exactly_ the same.

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid any error on months / days when parsing a date, it is probably better to use [DateTime.Parse or DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) than `ToDateTime`.

As [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1109183.aspx) and [this article](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-2-0-C-DateTime-IFormatProvider-Using-ParseExact.aspx) pointed out.

Comment: The problem the user has and doesn't understand is the user could input any calendar format, and only formats he checks for, would be able to be parsed.  Displaying the DateTime after being parsed in a specfic format is trivial.

Answer (score -1):

Try DateTime.Parse with an appropriate format provider. In your case it should be

```
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE", true);
DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text, culture );
```

Comment: This only works if the input matches the Culture provided.  It would fail for any other pattern

Comment: Yes, that is correct. As far as he asked for a given format I showed him an example how to use a format provider. As I sayd in the answer, he has to use an appropriate format provider. I just gave an example...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access it given a particular format, you should use DateTime.ToString(string format).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Comment: The author wants to take any user input and convert the provided format to a specfic format.  There is a reasn there are Calendar controls for this purpose.   A text field will only cause him problem, there are far to many, possible formats to check for.

Comment: My answer has to do with how to output a DateTime, not how to read it.  His question didn't ask for advice on which control to use.  For all I know, he is forced to use a text field.