# How can I convert a date string from format X to format Y?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string containing a date in some format X (e.g. `12/31/2015`). How can I convert it to format Y (e.g. `2015-12-31 00:00:00`)?

Comment: Note: This is meant to be a canonical question, to have a single, one-size-fits-all duplicate for all the *How do I convert my date from format ... to format ...?* questions. Feel free to add better answers or to improve mine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert date from yyyyMMdd format to mm-dd-yyyy format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712335/how-to-convert-date-from-yyyymmdd-format-to-mm-dd-yyyy-format)

Comment: There seems to already be a suitable "canonical" question. Please explain why a whole new question needs to be created, rather than simply cleaning up (if even necessary) the other one.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I did not find a suitable existing canonical question, which is why I have created a new one. The question you linked to is only about parsing to System.DateTime (and it has later been edited, so the answers don't really fit the question any more). Instead of also editing the answers (which would move the question quite far away from what it previously was), my idea was to create a new, "clean" one.

Comment: Well, if you don't like that one, here's another candidate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674355/convert-date-from-mm-dd-yyyy-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy-format. Is there some mechanism for users finding "canonical" questions that I'm not aware of? I suspect this question is just going to wind up no easier to find than any of the other multitude of questions that already amply explain how to convert back and forth between `string` and `DateTime`. :(

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Unfortunately, no; as far as I know, every power user has to keep his own list. Your link has a great answer, but it's a very specific question (and, thus, not a good dupe target). The thing is: I have [a dupe hammer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/138661) for C# questions, and, thus, I like to have a really *good, general* dupe to use before closing questions. Linking to one of the specific questions does not seem right, and cleaning up the one you linked to would change the meaning of the question (and the relevance of the answer) quite heavily.

Answer (score 3):

C# has it's own [`DateTime` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The goal is to

1. convert your string to a `DateTime` and then
2. convert your `DateTime` back to a string.

---

First, you need to get the *format string* for both formats X and Y. Check the following two lists:

- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

E.g., for `12/31/2015`, all of `d` or `MM/dd/yyyy` (with the en-US or invariant culture) or `MM\/dd\/yyyy` (with any locale) would be fine. For `2015-12-31 00:00:00`, it would be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

---

For the first step, you can use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) (or [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e(v=vs.110).aspx), if you want to fail gracefully if the string does not have the correct format), e.g.,

```
var myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myInputString, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

For the second step, use [DateTime.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var myOutputString = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple function based on Heinzi recommended method:

```
public string ConvertDateFormat(string input, string inputFormat, string outputFormat)
{       
       return DateTime.ParseExact(input, inputFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                      .ToString(outputFormat,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gQ11qs