# Change DateTime2 format in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is it possible to change the default DateTime2 format from ("MM/dd/yyyy") to ("dd/MM/yyyy")?

P/S : When I am using SomeDate.ToString() it shows the date with format ("MM/dd/yyyy"). I want the DateTime format to be ("dd/MM/yyy") without using SomeDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") and setting the date format in the Models.

Comment: Refer to the below link:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674355/convert-date-from-mm-dd-yyyy-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy-format>

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674355/convert-date-from-mm-dd-yyyy-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy-format>
Refer to above link

Comment: DateTime is not stored as a string! Use a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute on your models `DateTime` property to display it in the format you want (in conjunction with `@Html.DisplayFor()` or `@Html.EditorFor()` in the view (or just change the culture on your server to one that displays dates in the `dd/MM/yyyy` format)

Answer (score 1):

A DateTime value doesn't have a format. It just represents date and time (in the ISO calendar, and possibly in different time zones, but that's a different matter). It's like an int - it doesn't represent "a decimal integer" or "a hex integer" - it's just an integer within a particular range. You can format a number as decimal or hex, but it doesn't inherently have a format.

It sounds like you should parse it with ParseExact to specify the format when converting from the textbox, or probably TryParseExact:

```
// This is assuming you're absolutely sure of the format used. This is *not*
// necessarily the user's preferred format. You should think about where your
// data is coming from.
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // Okay, successful parse. We now have the date. Use it, avoiding formatting
    // it back to a string for as long as possible.
}
```

You should keep that value as DateTime for all purposes except giving it back to a user - at which point you may well want to use their cultural settings.

In particular, if you're storing the value in a database you should not convert it to text and include it in a SQL statement - that's asking for trouble. Instead, use a parameterized SQL statement and set it as the parameter value, still as a DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime2 isn't saved as a string literal like you're implying and is just a numeric value in the DateTime2 range. Conversion needs to happen to read it because it's probably something like 219,338,580,000,000,000 in the database saved as a long via nanoseconds. Anyway, you're going to have to convert it unless you want to make the less resourceful conversion to string and save it as a string and convert back to a datetime when used.

In your models use it I would suggest using it as a DateTime object and converting it ToString when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You environment selects the format you get when using the `ToString` without parameters. You have to define you format and set it to the environment. If you don't want to mess up your system, you can write extensions for the DateTime-class

I wrote an extension to use different output formats.

Reverse-Date-String for filenames. German-Date-String for textoutput..

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{
    public static string ToReverseShortDateString(this DateTime date)
    {
        return date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }

    public static string ToGermanDateString(this DateTime date)
    {
        return date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
    }
}
```

If you want to know more about extension-methods for existing classes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/extension-methods

Answer (score 0):

You have created your DbContext to hide how the data is saved in your database. Users of our DbContext shouldn't have to know whether a DateTime is saved as a string, or as the number of Ticks or whatever method. They only need to know the accuracy and the limits of your DbContext DateTime values (when different from System.DateTime).

Apparently you have modelled your DateTime values as "DateTime2". This has the effect that they have the same accuracy as System.DateTime.

Suppose the following DbContext with a Student

```
class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set}
    public Datetime Birthday {get;set;}
}
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // all DateTime are DateTime2
        modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
        ...
    }
}
```

Now if a user of this DbContext has the Birthday of a Student, it is a System.DateTime. Users of the DbContext don't have to know anything about the internal database format. My advise would be not to bother about this internal format, to make future changes easier.

If you use [System.DateTime.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it might be that the result is not in the format you want. To change this, you'll have to change CurrentCulture.CultureInfo, not the format that is used in the database.